# How to pass get the body of the SOAP XML message that has been sent to a @Endpoint/Controller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have an XML SOAP message which I am sending to my application.
In my case it goes directly to `@Endpoint` class and hits the method below:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = URI, localPart = "GetMagicalObject")
@ResponsePayload
public GetApplicationManifestResponseType getMagicalObject(@RequestPayload final GetMagicalObject magicalObject)
```

The SOAP message is correctly converted to the `magicalObject`. However, I also need the entire XML content of that request which has been sent to the endpoint.

I tried several things but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the XML, or in other words why do you need it?

Comment: I need to log the request to the dbdatabasefor audit purposes after the request is successful

Comment: Add a method argument of type `SoapMessage`, which you can then use to either get the `Source` or directly write to an `OutputStream`.